# Plot data from excel file

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to plot data that I save in the Excel file [Excel data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fy6wRFihmQIoX2knX1QgKottvZ_XyRsA/view?usp=sharing)

Frist column in the Excel file is the value of the x-axis while the other 4 are y-axis.

Comment: It seems that your question is not comprehensive, judging from the comments on the answer below. Please clarify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
data = Import[FileNameJoin[{$HomeDirectory, "Downloads", "graph data.xlsx"}]];
sheet1transpose = Transpose[data[[1]]];
xdata = sheet1transpose[[1]];
ydata = Rest[sheet1transpose];
plotdata = Map[Transpose[{xdata, #}] &, ydata];
chart = ListLinePlot[plotdata, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 2}, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
lines = Cases[chart, Line[_], Infinity];
data = Transpose[First[#]] & /@ lines;
x = data[[1, 1]];
y = data[[All, 2]];
joined = Prepend[y, x];
Print[If[joined === sheet1transpose, "Extract is the same", "Extract differs"]]
Export[FileNameJoin[{
   $HomeDirectory, "Downloads", "graph data 2.xlsx"}], Transpose[joined]]
```

Comment: Sir how can we take data of this graph in an excel file for mathematica.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you rephrase the question?

Comment: Sir, I want to take data of the plotted graph in Mathematica. tabulated data in Excel file.

Comment: Sounds like you now want to take the data *out of* the the graph, and put it back into an Excel file.  Is that right?

Comment: @Chis Degnen. yes, sir, I want this